# How can I retrieve some variables in another method

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to know the best way to retrieve the variable tag and msgCommit in the another method

```
public async run(commande){
 ...
}

public async test(){
  const tag = 123
  const msgCommit = await this.run('git rev-parse ' + tag )
...
}

public async test2(){
  // How can I retrieve tag and msgCommit
 ...
 }
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: You can return them from the function.. Something like `public async test(){
  const tag = 123
  const msgCommit = await this.run('git rev-parse ' + tag )
  return {msgCommit, tag}
}
`

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking here

Answer (score 1):

You're variables within `test()` have blocked-scope (as they're defined using `const`) and so cannot be accessed outside your function unless you `return` them. To do so, you need to wrap them in some sort of container such as an array:

```
public async test(){
  const tag = 123
  const msgCommit = await this.run('git rev-parse ' + tag )
  return [tag, msgCommit];
}
```

And now, you can access your variables `tag` and `msgCommit` inside your `test2()` method by calling `test()` within it.

However, all `async` functions will `return` a Promise implicitly (with the original return set as the resolve), and so, when you call `test()` you will get a Promise. This means your array will be wrapped within this Promise. To "extract" your array from the Promise, you can `await` (or use `.then()` on) the promise to get its contents once it has resolved:

```
public async test2() { // `async` so we can use `await` inside this method
  // How can I retrieve tag and msgCommit
  const [tag, msgCommit] = await test(); // destructure your array and store the elements as variables
  console.log(tag, msgCommit); 
}
```